# How to avoid terminal exit when a startup tmux session detached

Tags: terminal, tmux, gnome-shell

I have set my `zsh` auto start a tmux session when there is no one, like this

```
 if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
 fi
```

Yeah, this works fine, however when I detach the session, the terminal(I am using gnome-shell) will exit too. How do I avoid it

Comment: You could use `tmux` instead of `exec`, but that just raises the question of why you are using `exec` in the first place.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, it works as I want now, after change 'exec tmux' to 'tmux'. in fact I don't  known the difference between `tmux` and `exec tmux`, I just copy from somewhere in this site.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @chepner's comment, I just need to change `exec tmux` to `tmux`,
 because `exec`  executes a specified command, replacing the current process rather than starting a new subprocess.